# C#, ANTLR, ECMAScript grammar troubles

Tags: antlr3

I'm trying to parse JavaScript (ECMASCript) with C#.

I found the following instruction on how to create new project:
http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=557075

So I've downloaded ANTLRWorks, ANTLR v3, unpacked ANTLR, created a VS2010 project (.NET4), added references, checked and generated the grammar.

Then I recieved a lot of compilation error:

> The type or namespace name 'AstParserRuleReturnScope' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> The type or namespace name 'GrammarRule' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Stackoverlowed for them and got a solution: [antlr c# errors when integrating into VS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614953/antlr-c-sharp-errors-when-integrating-into-vs2008)

So I've downloaded new runtime, overwrite the old one and recompiled the project and got

> The name 'HIDDEN' does not exist in the current context   d:\Workspace.1\ScriptParser\ScriptParser\TestLexer.cs

Ok, I've changed HIDDEN to Hidden as recommended at in the following conversation: [[antlr-interest] How viable is the Csharp3 target? (more specific questions)](http://www.mail-archive.com/antlr-interest@antlr.org/msg06052.html)

Now I'm trying to parse the input. I found a few examples and wrote the following code:

```
using Antlr.Runtime;
namespace ScriptParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stream = new ANTLRStringStream("1+2");
            var lexer = new TestLexer(stream);
            var tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            var parser = new TestParser(tokenStream);
            // what exactly should be here???
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to parser JavaScript file with ANTLR but it seems that it will be the not as easy as I thought...

**Update:**

As suggested in  [Why are antlr3 c# parser methods private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411520/why-are-antlr3-c-sharp-parser-methods-private) I've modified the Test.g grammar by adding the "public" modified before the expr rule:

```
public expr : mexpr (PLUS^ mexpr)* SEMI! 
;
```

and then regenerated the code, replaced HIDDEN to Hidden (again) and modified the code as follows:

```
var stream = new ANTLRStringStream("1+2");
var lexer = new TestLexer(stream);
var tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new TestParser(tokenStream);
var result = parser.expr();
var tree = (CommonTree)result.Tree;
```

And not it is crashing on the line

```
root_0 = (object)adaptor.Nil();
```

in the following generated code

```
try { DebugEnterRule(GrammarFileName, "expr");
DebugLocation(7, 0);
try
{
    // d:\\Workspace.1\\ScriptParser\\ScriptParser\\Test.g:7:13: ( mexpr ( PLUS ^ mexpr )* SEMI !)
    DebugEnterAlt(1);
    // d:\\Workspace.1\\ScriptParser\\ScriptParser\\Test.g:7:15: mexpr ( PLUS ^ mexpr )* SEMI !
    {
    root_0 = (object)adaptor.Nil(); 

    DebugLocation(7, 15);
    PushFollow(Follow._mexpr_in_expr31);
```

with the NullReferenceException message because the adapter is null.

I've resolved it by adding

```
parser.TreeAdaptor = new CommonTreeAdaptor();
```

**Update 2:**

So, finally I've started with my primary task: parse JavaScript.

[ANTLR highlights](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) the ECMAScript grammar by Chris Lambrou.

So I've generated lexer/parser and run it with the very simple JavaScript code:

```
var f = function () { };
```

and the parsing fails with the following output from tree.ToStringTree():

```
<error: var q = function () { };>
```

Comment: Checkout this previous Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396080/antlr-3-3-c-sharp-tutorials

Comment: Thank you for excellent tutorial. As I understand, the rules in grammar should be converted to methods. I use grammar from http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=557075 and ANTLRWorks generate the "expr", "atom" and other methods, but they are private.

Comment: Thanks Alex. W.r.t. the private methods (parser rules), see another Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411520/why-are-antlr3-c-sharp-parser-methods-private

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I was getting exact same issues, and each of your solutions worked perfectly. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar rule says that there should be a semicolon at the end of the expression, but in you main function:

```
var stream = new ANTLRStringStream("1+2");
```

is missing a semicolon.  Shouldn't it be "1+2;"?

Comment: Certainly "1+2;" is valid Javascript.  But then so is "1+2" (or at least "1+2\n").   How does the ANTLR grammar handle the missing ";" question?